# What kind of runtime optimizations are lost if we use reflection

Tags: java, reflection

In this discussion about the performance overhead of using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html), it is stated:

> Use of reflection can cause some runtime optimizations to be lost. For example, the following code is highly likely be optimized by a Java virtual machine:
>
> ```
> int x = 1;
> x = 2;
> x = 3;
> ```
>
> Equivalent code using Field.set*() may not.

Without reflection, what kind of runtime optimizations would be done by JVM?

Comment: It would just run `x = 3`. All sorts of inlining tricks, opcode elimination, etc. go away when you throw reflection into the mix.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think it's too broad for a single SO question.

Comment: The assignments to x does nothing. It is a local variable, no multi-thread, no concurrency and can be removed. If you use Field.set other thread may have access to the variable so it can never be optimized. This is what I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of JIT optimizations can't be done. Just look into JDK source, setting a field value via reflection involves security checks, and some lookups.

while direct code on primitive values as outlined by your question will be jitted to a few assembly instructions, reflection calls give the optimizer very few information about what is going on, so little optimizations can be done.

If you benchmark it, you'll find out reflection is an order of a magnitude slower compared to "direct" code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last line? How did you arrive at the 'order of magnitude' conclusion?

Comment: Reflection can be almost as fast as direct code, depending on what you do and how you do it. In particular, the security checks and so on only have an impact on first access...

Comment: Just test it. (1) run a decent warmup (>10000 iterations) so JIT kicks in. Avoid loop-in-place-jitting fallacy.

Answer (score 3):

In this case the code can be discarded as it doesn't appear to do anything.

If you used reflection I suspect it would still do something although you can't access a local variable using reflection.